# Stringer can't generate constants with values from C enum

Tags: c, go, cgo, go-generate

I'm trying run `generate` on CGO project https://github.com/libgit2/git2go locally. I have successfully installed `libgit2` system library and can build and test the project with `go build -tags static,system_libgit2` and `go test -tags static,system_libgit2`.

The problem occurs when I try to generate additional files with `stringer`. The code I'm showing is located in master branch, so I suppose it should work correctly and the problem is on my side.

The file [diff.go](https://github.com/libgit2/git2go/blob/main/diff.go) has stringer annotation (removed unimportant parts):

```golang
package git
/*
#include <git2.h>

...
*/
import "C"
import (
    "errors"
    "runtime"
    "unsafe"
)

...

type Delta int

const (
    DeltaUnmodified Delta = C.GIT_DELTA_UNMODIFIED
    DeltaAdded      Delta = C.GIT_DELTA_ADDED
    DeltaDeleted    Delta = C.GIT_DELTA_DELETED
    DeltaModified   Delta = C.GIT_DELTA_MODIFIED
    DeltaRenamed    Delta = C.GIT_DELTA_RENAMED
    DeltaCopied     Delta = C.GIT_DELTA_COPIED
    DeltaIgnored    Delta = C.GIT_DELTA_IGNORED
    DeltaUntracked  Delta = C.GIT_DELTA_UNTRACKED
    DeltaTypeChange Delta = C.GIT_DELTA_TYPECHANGE
    DeltaUnreadable Delta = C.GIT_DELTA_UNREADABLE
    DeltaConflicted Delta = C.GIT_DELTA_CONFLICTED
)

//go:generate stringer -type Delta -trimprefix Delta -tags static

...
```

This type is referencing to `libgit2` C enum, the part of `/usr/include/git2/diff.h`:

```c
/**
 * What type of change is described by a git_diff_delta?
 *
 * `GIT_DELTA_RENAMED` and `GIT_DELTA_COPIED` will only show up if you run
 * `git_diff_find_similar()` on the diff object.
 *
 * `GIT_DELTA_TYPECHANGE` only shows up given `GIT_DIFF_INCLUDE_TYPECHANGE`
 * in the option flags (otherwise type changes will be split into ADDED /
 * DELETED pairs).
 */
typedef enum {
    GIT_DELTA_UNMODIFIED = 0,  /**< no changes */
    GIT_DELTA_ADDED = 1,      /**< entry does not exist in old version */
    GIT_DELTA_DELETED = 2,    /**< entry does not exist in new version */
    GIT_DELTA_MODIFIED = 3,    /**< entry content changed between old and new */
    GIT_DELTA_RENAMED = 4,     /**< entry was renamed between old and new */
    GIT_DELTA_COPIED = 5,      /**< entry was copied from another old entry */
    GIT_DELTA_IGNORED = 6,     /**< entry is ignored item in workdir */
    GIT_DELTA_UNTRACKED = 7,   /**< entry is untracked item in workdir */
    GIT_DELTA_TYPECHANGE = 8,  /**< type of entry changed between old and new */
    GIT_DELTA_UNREADABLE = 9,  /**< entry is unreadable */
    GIT_DELTA_CONFLICTED = 10, /**< entry in the index is conflicted */
} git_delta_t;
```

When I run command `go generate` I'm getting error:

```
stringer: can't happen: constant is not an integer DeltaUnmodified
diff.go:43: running "stringer": exit status 1
```

I tried to run these commands:

- `go generate ./diff.go`
- `go generate -tags static,system_libgit2`
- `go generate -tags static,system_libgit2  ./diff.go`

But it always shows the same error.

How to correctly generate file with stringer for Go constants with values from C enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringer` works by simply [parsing](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/589136c8afd9ea08dadd98d6d768ad2c247a300f/cmd/stringer/stringer.go#L260) Go source with `go.ast` to extract the needed constant values. The values must be integer literals specified at the definition site (see [source](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/589136c8afd9ea08dadd98d6d768ad2c247a300f/cmd/stringer/stringer.go#L445)).

CGo works by generating Go shims for C code. For example, C constants go into the `_cgo_gotypes.go` file as `const _Ciconst_... = ...` shims.

Normally CGo deletes generated files when done, but you can keep them by invoking it explicitly, e.g. `go tool cgo main.go`.

So you should be able to do something like this:

```
go tool cgo main.go
mv _obj/_cgo_gotypes.go _obj/cgo_gotypes.go
stringer -type Delta -trimprefix Delta ./_obj
cp _obj/delta_strings.go .
```